# TFS API Create Branch Programmatically visualization

Tags: tfs

I have a folder into tfs,and I want to take branch of this folder with creating new folder and put branch under this new folder programmatically.Normally when we do it in tfs it automatically change folder to branch.

When I use createbranch command ,it works ,create folder and under these new folder it create new branch,but branch seen like folder in tfs but I can merge it vs so it is working.If I want to change visualization I have to use second command CreateBranchObject.Is it possible to that in one command

Folder A-->take new branch

Folder A'(New Folder) --> Branch

Code Sample

```
int changesetId = VersionControlServer.CreateBranch(@"myfolder ", "mynewfolder\newbranch", 
                                                    VersionSpec.Latest);
Changeset changeset = vcs.GetChangeset(changesetId);

changeset.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not like in a single command and you will need to call both in sequence.